# Hibernate unproxy object with lazy relations while debugging

Tags: java, hibernate, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm debugging a hibernate application, while debugging I want to check the entities.

`Hibernate.unproxy(entity)` just works for plain types and not for relations within the entity (`FetchType` is lazy). They are all still of type `HibernateProxy`.
Of course as soon as I unproxy the relations, I get the result. But for entities with a lot of relations this is quite cumbersome.

Is there a way to unproxy an object with all relations?

My IDE is intelliJ Idea if that is of any relevance.